# Why was this character in Avengers: Infinity War in Vormir?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

We know Red Skull is in Captain America: The First Avenger, but why is he in Vormir in the first place? How did he get there?

Apart from Marvel trying to close Phase: One, what was the point of portraying this character in this movie?

Comment: He was teleported there via tesseract. It was covered in this question https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88353/what-happened-to-red-skull-at-the-end-of-captain-america-the-first-avenger